# AppleTV 4K flashes in white periodically

Tags: appletv

I have AppleTV 4K connected to Sony XE9005 TV via HDMI 2 port (HDR enabled).

The TV is flashing in white periodically (like each 3 minutes or so). AppleTV automatically chooses 4K HDR and it picks Chroma 4:2:0

The HDMI cable is the one that Apple sells in the stores from Belkin.

Any ideas what is going on? Or just crossing fingers and hoping that a new update is going to fix it?

Comment: I'd try a different HDMI cable, if you have one, to see if the cable is the problem.

Comment: @IconDaemon I am using the expensive one from AppleStore and it is recommended by them for AppleTV 4K

Comment: Expensive does not equal performance. It should be at least have the HDMI High Speed specification. Because the cable is a physical object, it is also subject to damage, some of which might not be visible.

Comment: Reading the comments on [this page](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/tvs-entertainment/7976/expensive-hdmi-cables-make-no-difference-and-heres-why) leads me to believe that the newer HDMI standards (4K in particular) do require a better-than-average physical construction because the data has greater bandwidth needs. A poorly shielded cable, or one with less than stellar connectors and internal construction, will affect the bandwidth of the signal, which will lead to degradation.

Comment: @IconDaemon my cable is braided with another HDMI cable of PS4 Pro. Plus, AppleTV is very close to the PS4, should I put it away a little bit? Or is it possible to shield the cables from each other

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70036/discussion-between-icondaemon-and-chiron).

Comment: I have the exact same setup, new AppleTV 4K and Sony XE9005 and I experiene on HDMI2 AppleTV 4k flashes, white and some times a weird sort of filter style burn on the image. I also have Chrima 4:2:0 have tried 4:2:2 but was not able to get a pictures but running on 4K HDR. I bought a brand new high quality cable to replace the current high quality cable :-) but just the same :-) Any help greatly appreciated. I also have Sony UltraHD 4K player HDMI 3 same cables no problems just perfect.